How to manage EU import duty relief on personal possessions when moving to one EU country but temporarily storing them in another?
I'm currently based in the UK. I got a job in Germany but it's unlikely I will be able to get permanent housing until much later into me being here (due to the horrid rental market in Berlin). I'd like to place my stuff into storage at my parents' place in Poland.
The way I understand it both Germany and Poland offer a full duty relief on import stuffs for personal possessions associated with a move of residence from outside the EU. However, all of the information I've been able to find on how this actually happens is that they require a proof that I will be moving to that specific country. But because they exist in a customs union, my possessions landing in one country are technically already cleared for the entire customs area - so I would be able to move them Poland->Germany with no declarations being needed.
I'm confused on how to proceed about it. Part of it is not really understanding at which point the goods entering by road are checked, and by which country's customs authorities.

Are you going to move your belongings yourself, or are you going to use a moving company? If the latter, they may have answers for you. If your new employer is large enough, and especially if it’s an intra-company transfer, HR may be able to help you as well.

there's lots of man-with-a-van UK->Poland services which is what I would ideally use (because costs) but they don't do anything but very basic customs
